# Can't load SQLsrv due to "zval_ptr_dtor" error

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to install the PHP MSSQL Driver following this guide: https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-install-the-php-sqlsrv-extension

But I keep running into this error after the installation (no apparent errors during the installation itself):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor), /usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

For my eyes, the main issue is this one:

```
/usr/lib/php/20170718/sqlsrv.so: undefined symbol: zval_ptr_dtor
```

I have tried uninstalling and starting over two times now, but keep being stumped by this. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

I run PHP 7.2.14-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1.

Comment: Looks like a plain old typo. Exactly what are you doing? Please post every detail.

Comment: I did ask for _every detail_. For instance, this tutorial advised you to create a `sqlsrv.ini` file. Where did you create it and what did you put in it?

Comment: I created it in my /etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d directory, and used the guide as described. It also contains the content from echo command as it should. I tried going the direct way instead, and having the .so files included directly in the php.ini file, but with no luck.

Comment: But you're running PHP 7.2?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I ended up doing a complete clean reinstall of the whole thing, so I never found the exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with a different plugin and this was my solution. When installing an .so addon with pecl, I noticed an error at the end:

> configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location

To fix that I just typed this (for mine I have php version 8) and now it works:

```
pear config-set php_ini /etc/php/8.0/apache2/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I realized that I was wrong in compile module. I've got in my environment

- php 7.2
- php-config 7.3

So I unistall modules:

```
sudo pecl uninstall sqlsrv
sudo pecl uninstall pdo_sqlsrv
```

set php-config 7.2 as default and install again.

Comment: How did you set the php-config to 7.2 ?